# Installing Phalcon PHP Devtools: "ERROR: Phalcon extension isn't installed ..." though the module is installed

Tags: php, installation, php-extension, phalcon, devtools

After some days ago I installed `Phalcon PHP`, I am more and more exited about it. Now I want to try the `Phalcon Devtools` out. I've just installed it like in the [`installation manual via Composer`](https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools#installing-via-composer) (for Linux) shown. But when I try to execute the `phalcon` command, I get an error:

```
$ phalcon commands
ERROR: Phalcon extension isn't installed, follow these instructions to install it: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html
```

What can be the problem?

(Environment: `Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)`, `PHP 5.5.11-1`).

---

Additional information:

I installed [Phalcon PHP](http://phalconphp.com) like in the [docu](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html) shown:

```
$ apt-get install php5-dev libpcre3-dev gcc make php5-mysql
$ git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
$ cd cphalcon/build
$ ./install
```

Since it seemed to not work, I tried it with

```
$ cd cphalon/build/64bits
$ export CFLAGS="-O2 --fvisibility=hidden"
$ ./configure --enable-phalcon
$ make && make install
```

After that the module was compiled and the `phalcon.so` created in the PHP modules direcroty `/usr/lib/php5/20121212`. Then I created the `INI` file `/etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini` (with content `extension=phalcon.so`) manually and enabled it with a symlink: `ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini`. And after a restart it worked. I created a "Hello World!" application and the module was also displayed in the `phpinfo()` output:

[image]

But the output of `php --modules` does not contain "phalcon". And the output of [`get_loaded_extensions()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) does not contain it as well. Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to both questions (1. Why do I get an error? and 2. Why `php --modules` doesn't show the module, though `phpinfo()` (in browser) does?) is the same: I enabled the module for FPM, but didn't do this for the CLI.

```
$ ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini
```

Now it works!

Comment: Any idea on how to do this on windows ?

Comment: Sry if i lift this up. BIG THANKS! You saved my day.

Comment: i had to edit the file /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini and remove the ;

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem on **Windows 10** with **WAMP** installed.
I shows on the phpinfo() but on the command prompt is gives the error.

When you enter c:\>**php -m** to show the available php modules its not there...

First look where your php.ini file is with the command:

c:\>**php --ini**

In my case: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\php.ini

After editing this file and adding **extension=php_phalcon.dll** it works and when you enter then the phalcon command it gives you the available version and commands.

C:\>**phalcon**

C:\>phalcon-tools

Phalcon DevTools (3.0.1)

Available commands:

commands         (alias of: list, enumerate)
  controller       (alias of: create-controller)
  module           (alias of: create-module)
  model            (alias of: create-model)
  all-models       (alias of: create-all-models)
  project          (alias of: create-project)
  scaffold         (alias of: create-scaffold)
  migration        (alias of: create-migration)
  webtools         (alias of: create-webtools)

How it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, but let me tell you here, @Jubayer Arefin.

You need to put your phalcon-devtools path inside %PATH% variable. It's explained in phalcon-devtools docs in install section on their site.

Comment: Phalcon is already in his path for him to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> $ phalcon commands
>   ERROR: Phalcon extension isn't installed, follow these instructions to install it: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html

I fixed the same problem in Windows:

The problem was in my `System Path` variable: another old PHP path in it, and the CMD was taking the first (the old one without phalcon extension) by default.
Delete this old path, put the correct one -- and it will work!